# How to take out list matching their timestamp using awk?

Tags: linux, awk, pattern-matching

using `awk`, I want to filter lines with their time stamp

I tried

```
awk '/29/Dec/2016-07:52/' filename
```

but it's giving error

> awk: /29/Dec/2016-07:52/
>
> awk:                ^ syntax error

how to take out list matching their timestamp?

Comment: You should escape the `/` in the date, like: `/29\/Dec\/2016-07:52/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `/` is being used as the delimiter so you need to escape it:

```
awk '/29\/Dec\/2016-07:52/' filename
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to worry about escaping, you can use a different variant:

```
awk '$0 ~ "29/Dec/2016-07:52"' filename
```

Of course, if you're simply after the extraction of lines containing those strings, `awk` is probably overkill - you can do this with `grep`:

```
grep -F '29/Dec/2016-07:52' filename
```

Comment: Just wanted to add here in paxdiablo's answer here, "/" having special meaning so we have to use escape sequence to tell awk that do not take it's special meaning we are looking for same character "/" not for it's special meaning.

Comment: That second one is not a non-regex variant, it's just using a dynamic regexp instead of a constant regexp. A non-regexp variant would be `awk 'index($0,"29/Dec/2016-07:52")' filename`. Also `/` is the constant regexp delimiter, not a separator.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for the comments, have adjusted the answer to suit.